# Is there any solution to map CSV data to object at runtime in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I tried using CSVHelper GetRecords. Its not working for iOS.Kindly anyone help on this.I need to map csv data to any object at runtime,without parsing for seperate object each and every time. Always CSVHelper fails in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceStack.Text](http://components.xamarin.com/view/servicestacktext) has a Xamarin component that includes CSV support